# Select the <li> without <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `<ul>` list with `<a>` links. I would like to find the `<li>` **WITHOUT** `<a>` and wrap a `<a>` to it.

How can I check if the `<li>` has no `<a>` (in this case `<li>hello</li>`)?

```
<ul class="sorter">
    <li>
        <a href="url">blabla</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        hello
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [:has](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) for this:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3wk2317/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("ul.sorter li:not(:has('a'))").each(function()
    {
        $(this).append('<a href="#">added</a>');
    });
});
```

**Update** To wrap `<li>` text with `<a>`:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3wk2317/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("ul.sorter li:not(:has('a'))").each(function()
    {
        $(this).html('<a href="#">' + $(this).text() + '</a>');
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry, i mean wrap. not append. my bad

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".sorter li").each(function(){
    var li = $(this)
    var a_tag = li.find('a');
    //without <a> tag
    if( a_tag.length == 0 ){
        //keep content in <li>
        var li_txt = li.html();
        //add <a> tag
        li.html('<a href="#">' + li_txt + '</a>');
    }
});
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/c0ukahzn/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) for it.

add the following line in the head of your html

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

then at the end of the body add the following

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('body ul').find('li').each(function(){
           var isA = $(this).find('a');
           if(isA.length == 0){
             $(this).append('<a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>');
           }
        });
    });
</script>
```